# In a function show passed arguments in a different color

Tags: emacs, elisp

How to configure emacs to show passed arguments inside a function in a different color?

Comment: can you give an example? did you try font-lock?

Comment: There is no font lock for arguments of a function...or at least I dont know of one.
Basically, I want X,Y,Z be a customized color in the function func:
void func(int x, int y, int z) {
X=Y;
X++;
for (z = 1; z < y; z++) x++;
}
something like that.

Comment: That won't be simple. Font locking doesn't store information about what each symbol means, it simply guesses the meaning by parsing each line independently.

Comment: You would need a function that colors the buffer manually and gets run every so often.

Comment: barracel, that is actually not a duplicate question. I was not asking about the variable types to be colored the same. My specific request is to color (passed variables) differently in the function, so even if I have two integers passed in a function I want them to be colored differently.